# SASS Grandparent selector

Tags: sass

I have next problem. If .a style has child style .b, then set another value to attribute of .a class.

```
.a {
    padding-right: 16px;
}


.a {
    .b {
        // Here I'm trying to set padding-right: 0 to the .a style
    }
}
```

Is it possible to detect that parent style contains something child style? Can I solve this using variable (see example) ?

```
.a {
    $a-style: &;
    .b {
      .#{$a-style} {
        padding-right: 0;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the `:has` pseudo-class (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), but unfortunately it is not currently (September 2021) supported by any browsers.